# How to force remove products from WooCommerce cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm building a site with Wordpress and WooCommerce for someone for the purposes of a business, but they have certain items that cannot be sold together - essentially the opposite of a force sell or chained products. If a customer puts product A in their cart, I don't want them to be able to put product C in with it, but B and D are fine. Alternatively, when it goes to checkout, separating the products into two separate orders would work as well. Is there any way to do this?  This is my first time using Wordpress, so I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: You will need to write your own code. psuedo code when adding to cart

`if( cart has product B && current prodcut is A ){
 //call the set_quantity() method inside the WooCommerce cart class. You can access this through the global $woocommerce object:
 global $woocommerce
 $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity();

 //The first parameter is the cart_item_key which you can look up in the cart_contents property of the same class. The second parameter is the new quantity, which you will like to set to 0 in order to remove an item from the cart.
 
}else {
 add product to cart
}`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm pretty new to PHP - any ideas on a good place to start?  Maybe a website that will help with better understanding concepts?

Comment: As a follow-up for future visitors, I believe [Conditional Payments and Shipping](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-conditional-shipping-and-payments/) will handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code below :

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler','mycustomfuncion',11,2);
function mycustomfuncion($p,$q)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartItem = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;
    $currentProductId = $q->id;
    foreach($cartItem as $item)
    {
        $productItemId = $item['product_id'];
        ///your condition will be here

    }
    return $q;
}
```

You will get all product ids which are in cart by the $productItemId. And you will get current product id (which user wants to add to cart ) by $currentProductId. After your conditions if you want to allow to add to cart the product then return $q from the function otherwise don't return any value.